# what does " set -- ${@:2} " mean in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script, and a line in that is "set -- ${@:2}", could you please tell me what does it mean?
I have tried in my test script, it seems to remove the $1 param in args, could you help me with more details?

Comment: You'll want to look in section 3.5.3, *Shell Parameter Expansion*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a complicated way of writing `shift`.*

First, what is `set --`?

- `set` has many uses. It can change shell options, for instance with `set -e` to enable strict error checking or `set -x` to print each command that's run.
- `set` can also change the `$1`, `$2`, etc., command-line arguments. `set foo bar baz` sets `$1` to `"foo"`, `$2` to `"bar"`, and `$3` to `"baz"`.
- `--` is a common idiom that means "stop looking for flags". If you write `set -e` then you get error checking, but with `set -- -e` the `-e` is no longer a flag, it's now the value of `$1`.

Okay, and what about`"${@:2}"`?

- `"$@"` is the list of command-line arguments. Writing `"$@"` is like writing `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` for however many arguments there are.
- `:2` is array slice notation. It gives you the elements of an array starting at the 2nd element. `"${@:2}` gives you all the command-line arguments starting with the second. It's like writing `"$2" "$3" "$4" ...`.
- `$var` is shorthand for `${var}`. Curly braces are optional for simple expansions, required for more complicated ones. To use array slicing, `"$@"` must be written as `"${@}"`. `"$@:2"` doesn't work: the shell parses it as `"${@}:2"`.

Put them together and you get "set the command-line arguments to `$2`, `$3`, `$4`, etc." Or, as you said, it gets rid of `$1`.

Which is exactly what `shift` does.

<sup>* Actually, `shift` is equivalent to `set -- "${@:2}"` with double quotes. Missing double quotes is a bug that'll bite you if any argument contains whitespace or globbing characters (`*`, `?`, etc.). When in doubt, always quote variable expansions!</sup>

Comment: It's complicated *bash-specific* way of writing `shift`.

Comment: @GemTaylor What's the distinction you're making? `set -- "${@:2}"` also preserves `$0`, and with both `$1` is overwritten.

Comment: `set` doesn't change `$0`.